# App icon doesn't appear in action bar while using Theme.appCompat.light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons, android-appcompat

I am following a tutorrial to make a Navigation Drawer using supported library V7 so i had to use Theme.appCompat.light.DarkActionBar as the app theme...

The problem is:

1. App Icon doesn't appear in the default place in the Action Bar.
2. The drawer icon is shifted to the right

Here is my Code:

```
package com.tutorial18nav.tutorial18nav;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerlist;
    String[] sections;
    private android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        sections = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sections);
        mDrawerlist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sections));
        mDrawerlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        mDrawerToggle = new android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Drawer is opened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Drawer is closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Section number " + (position + 1) + " has been selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        selectItem(position);
    }

    public void selectItem(int position) {

        mDrawerlist.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(sections[position]);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            return true;
        }
        if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }    
}
```

Activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:background="#FF8800"
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left">
    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tutorial18nav.tutorial18nav"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.tutorial18nav.tutorial18nav.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```